# Use APC to store generated html

Tags: php, caching, apc

Some of our pages use a lot of processing power so when users are not signed in it makes sense to completely cache them.

I'm using `apc` and the following code to try and accomplish this:

```
$key = "forum-thread-list-cache";

if(($data = apc_fetch($key)) === false) {

    ob_start();

        $forumOb = new Forum();
        $threadList = $forumOb->getThreadList();

        require "templates/forum.php";

    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    //Debugging
    file_put_contents("/home/user/log.txt", $data);

    //15 Minutes
    apc_store($key, $data, 60 * 15);

    flush();
}
```

Currently the generated html will appear in the `log.txt` file but I can't get it to appear in the apc user cache entries?

The generated html is around 18kb in size.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Here are my runtime settings, is there anything in here that would prevent 18kb of html being cached?

[image: Apc Settings]

Comment: `apc_store` returns `true` when the data is stored successfully and `false` on failure. What do you get? Also, what information does `apc_cache_info('user')` return? Are you sure you've got a working APC?

Comment: Yes `apc_store` returns true but the data doesn't appear in the apc.php screen and it runs store every time it loads. Apc is working because I can store, fetch and delete query data just not this html. I've added a screenshot of my runtime settings.

Comment: The code and settings look fine to me. Assuming you're running all code through your web server and not the CLI, I can't think of much else than trying to debug 1) without TTL in `apc_store()`, 2) with some other content, 3) whether `apc_exists('forum-thread-list-cache')` returns true right after your `apc_store()` call. A variable size of 18 kB should not be a problem.

Comment: @Viktor it must be something to do with the html that's being generated in that loop, the require should basically echo once it's run and be stored in `ob_get_contents();` right?

Comment: @Viktor it was a stupid mistake, the php inside the required file also had a `$key` so the key name changed and it cached it as the wrong name.

Comment: OK, I didn't think of that possibility. Good thing you got it working! =)